# Python numpy assigning values to a 2D array using another array with ordered pairs as indices to the 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

This is hard to describe in words but easy to see in practice. I have a 2D array:

```
im = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
```

I'm interpreting it as a 4x4 grayscale image - so the values in the array are simply intensities. So, to start with, `im` is:

```
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0]]
```

I want to be able to change many values in the "image" at once according to an array of x values and an array of y values. I assemble them to look like ordered pairs in a second array like this:

```
x = [0,1]
y = [2,3]
coords = np.array([x,y]).T
```

Now `coords` looks like this:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
```

Finally, I want to index im by coords. I thought perhaps it was something like this:

```
im[coords] = 9
```

...but that doesn't work. I'd like the final result of im to be:

```
[[0,0,9,0],
 [0,0,0,9],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0]]
```

Does anyone know of a fast and elegant way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `im[x, y] = 9` work?

Comment: haha... yes, indeed it does! I could have sworn I tried that! Oh well, it's not the dumbest thing I've done recently, but it's right up there :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
x_coords = [0, 1]
y_coords = [2, 3]
values = [8, 9]
```

then

```
arr[x, y] = values
```

will result in

```
  array([
        [0, 0, 8, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 9],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ])
```

Comment: This is just repeating what was said in comments

Comment: @RafaelC I also wanted to add that you can give a list of values as well, which was not given in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `im[x,y] = 9`.

ex:

```
im = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
x = [0,1]
y = [2,3]
im[x,y] = 9
print(im)
# Result:
# array([[0, 0, 9, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 9],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: This is just repeating what was said in comments